# Checked install components

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How can I check third-party components that is property installed before the web page start in web.config. And throw error before start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find something about the component that your code can test, then have the code test it. Best place for testing it would probably be the Application_Start event handler in global.asax.

What to test depends on what kind of component you are talking about. You could use reflection to attempt to locate information about a known assembly if the component is a compiled assembly referenced by your application, or you could use System.IO to check a physical file on the file system that should exist. You could possibly even call a constructor on some object from the component and verify that it instantiates correctly.